# How to change the value of an array list

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm importing the CSV file shown below into powershell. It becomes an Array List but I am unable to update anything in this array. I would like to set Extension 103 to "Test". The code that I thought would work is under the foreach loop. The foreach loop is used to find the extension with no name value assigned.

```
$i = 0
Foreach($item in $LIST){
    if($List.User[$i] -eq ""){
        write-host $list.extension[$i] + "This is empty"
        break
        $list.user[$i] = "TEST"
    }
    $i++
}

$list.user[3] = "Test"
```

This is what my CSV file looks like:

```
"Extension","User"
"100","John Doe"
"101","Bob Smith"
"102","Ben Frank"
"103",""
```

Comment: Please post an example CSV file with a couple of lines, and clarify what you mean by "user" and "extension." (Remember, we can't see your screen!)

Answer (score 1):

You were close.

```
$list[3].user = "Test"
```

$list.user "calculates" a list of the user properties, but it's no longer connected to the $list.

$list[3] is the 4th item in $list.

Comment: This will change the name of the extension. I want to change the User name that is linked to the extension.

Comment: This was very helpful though. I was able to assign all users to $users using      $users = $list.user and then I did $users[3] = "$Test"

Answer (score 0):

```
$list[3].user = "Test"
```

This will update the user in row 3